# Android Configuration settings

Tags: android, android-camera

I am having a problem with my camera preview.It seems stretched on wide screen

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
 camera.startPreview();
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

you should check this resource https://github.com/pikanji/CameraPreviewSample.
It works really great and it helped me a lot few dayes ago.

Cheers ;)